# Repeat a ggplot for each value of a variable in the dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, apply

I want to make a graph for each value of a variable in my dataframe, and then pass that value through to the graph as the title. I *think* the best way to do this is by using the `apply()` family of functions, but i'm a bit of a novice and can't figure out how to do that.

For example, say I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(month=c("Chair", "Table", "Rug", "Wardrobe", "Chair", "Desk", "Lamp", "Shelves", "Curtains", "Bed"),
                 cutlery=c("Fork", "Knife", "Spatula", "Spoon", "Corkscrew", "Fork", "Tongs", "Chopsticks", "Spoon", "Knife"),
                 type=c("bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb"),
                 count=c(341, 527, 2674, 811, 1045, 4417, 1178, 1192, 4793, 916))
```

I could manually go through and select on the value of `type` doing this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(type=='aaa') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(month, count)) +
  labs(title = 'value of {{type}} being plotted')

df %>% 
  filter(type=='bbb') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(month, count)) +
  labs(title = 'value of {{type}} being plotted')

df %>% 
  filter(type=='ccc') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(month, count)) +
  labs(title = 'value of {{type}} being plotted')
```

But this quickly becomes a lot of code, with enough levels of `type` and assuming a fair amount of additional code for each plot. Let's also assume that I don't want to use `facet_wrap(~type)`. As you can see, the values of the x variable vary quite a lot across values of type so `facet_wrap()` results in lots of missing spaces along the x-axis. Ideally i'd just create a function that takes as an input the x and y variables, and `type` and then filters on `type`, makes the plot, and extracts the value of `type` to use in the title.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can create your custom function and then `lapply` over the levels of `type`

```
myplot <- function(var){
  df %>% 
    filter(type==var) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(month, count)) +
    labs(title = paste0("value of ",var))
}
plot.list <- lapply(unique(df$type), myplot)
plot.list[[1]]
plot.list[[2]]
plot.list[[3]]
```

**EDIT**

to include the x variable as argument::

```
myplot <-
  function(var, xvar) {
    df %>%   
      filter(type == var) %>%   
      ggplot() + 
      geom_col(aes(x={{xvar}}, count)) +   
      labs(title = paste0("value of ", var))
  }

plot.list <- lapply(unique(df$type), myplot,xvar=cutlery)
```

you miss the `{{}}` (aka 'curly curly') operator that replaces the approach of quoting with `enquo` and unquoting with `!!` (aka 'bang-bang'), and the argument `xvar` has to be passed as an extra argument of `lapply` and not of the function inside `lapply`

Comment: All the answers are great. I'm keen to use lapply(). I wonder if there's a way to integrate passing x and y to the myplot function? Say, something like this (i've tried running this and it returns an error, but hopefully it's clear what my intention is): 

```myplot <- function(var, x){
  df %>% 
    filter(type==var) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x, count)) +
    labs(title = paste0("value of ",var))
}
plot.list <- lapply(unique(df$type), myplot(x=cutlery))```. I've added an additional column to the df above called `cutlery`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the data for each value of `type` and generate a list of plots.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(type) %>%
  map(~ggplot(.x) +
        geom_col(aes(month, count)) +
        labs(title = sprintf('value of %s being plotted', 
                              first(.x$type)))) -> plot_list
```

`plot_list[[1]]` returns :

[image]

and `plot_list[[2]]` returns -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your statement "Ideally i'd just create a function that takes as an input the x and y variables, and type ..." I assume you specifically want to have a function that takes `x` and `y` as different variables (e.g. vectors) as inputs rather than taking the whole `dataframe` as an input. In this case, this function may suit your needs:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

myPlot_function = function(x, y, type) {
        
        gg_list = list() # empty list
        df = data.frame(x, y, type)
        type_n = length(unique(df$type)) # number of each type
        
        for (i in 1:type_n){ # loop over each type
                
                g = df %>%
                        filter(type == type[i]) %>%
                        ggplot() +
                        geom_col(aes(x, y)) +
                        labs(title = paste0("Value of ", type[i], " being plotted"))
                gg_list[[paste0("plot_", i)]] = g
        }
        return(gg_list)
}
```

And then, you can specify your `x` and `y` and `type` as vectors. For example:

```
some_plots = myPlot_function(x = df$month, y = df$count, type = df$type)
```

The function `myPlot_function` returns a `list` containing your plots. You can now either use `some_plots$plot_1` or `some_plots[[1]]` to see your plot. For example:

```
some_plots$plot_1
```

[image]